# XSL-FO processor for JAVA: Transform xml to pdf

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

As I can transform an XML to PDF using XSL -FO file with Java?
I've heard about ApacheFOP but can not find the code

Answer (score 1):

Have a Look at http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/
Hope that helps - Stefan